# R Shiny: How to disable/enable slider via checkbox?

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, slider

The following code produces an example with three sliders and three checkboxes.

If one checkbox is ticked the slider below should be disbaled. That means the selected value should not be modifiable by the slider anymore.

Furthermore the sum of all slider values should not extend the maximum value, in this case 10.

```
library(shiny)

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("title panel"),
    sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                  sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                               checkboxInput("check1", "disable/enable", value = T),
                               sliderInput("slider1","value 1",min=1,max=10,value=3),
                               checkboxInput("check2", "disable/enable", value = F),
                               sliderInput("slider2","Value 2",min=1,max=10,value=3),
                               checkboxInput("check3", "disable/enable", value = F),
                               sliderInput("slider3","Value 3",min=1,max=10,value=3)
                  ),
                  mainPanel("main panel")
                  )))

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output){})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

Comment: see `disable` and `enable` from `library(shinyjs)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will meet your needs

```
u <- fluidPage(
                useShinyjs(),
                sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                             checkboxInput("check1", "disable/enable", value = F),
                             uiOutput("slidr1"),
                             checkboxInput("check2", "disable/enable", value = F),
                             uiOutput("slidr2"),
                             checkboxInput("check3", "disable/enable", value = F),
                             uiOutput("slidr3")
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel")

)

s <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$slidr1 <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider1","Value 1",min=1,max=8,value=3)
  })
  
  output$slidr2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$slider1)
    max2 <- reactive({9-(input$slider1 )})
    sliderInput("slider2","Value 2",min=1,max=max2(),value=3)
  })
  
  output$slidr3 <- renderUI({
    req(input$slider1,input$slider2)
    max3 <- reactive({10-(input$slider1 + input$slider2)})
    sliderInput("slider3","Value 3",min=1,max=max3(),value=3)
  })
  
  
  # Want the initial state of this button to be disabled?
  #shinyjs::disable(id="slider1")
  observeEvent(input$check1,{
    if (input$check1) shinyjs::disable(id="slider1")  
    else shinyjs::enable(id="slider1") 
  })
    
  observeEvent(input$check2,{
    if (input$check2) shinyjs::disable(id="slider2")  
    else shinyjs::enable(id="slider2") 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$check3,{
    if (input$check3) shinyjs::disable(id="slider3") 
    else shinyjs::enable(id="slider3") 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui=u, server=s)
```